# FCM delay in messaging or never receive

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed a real-time on-demand app using FCM to notify my riders of jobs. But the problem comes that these messages sometimes never arrived at the rider's app within 1 minute timespan.

I would like to understand why such latency occurs, and to use any logs from FCM side to prove issue is not with my codes and is on the FCM server side. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Interested in this aswell.